# Question about the Rank Nullity Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Im having a little trouble seeing one of the consequences of the rank-nullity theorem, namely the second one:

(Rank-Nullity Theorem). For vector spaces $V, W$ and a lin-
ear mapping $\Phi : V \rightarrow W$ it holds that
$dim(ker(\Phi)) + dim(Im(\Phi)) = dim(V )$ .

The following are direct consequences:

If $dim(Im(\Phi)) < dim(V )$ , then ker(Φ) is non-trivial, i.e., the kernel
contains more than $0, V$ and $dim(ker(\Phi)) > 1$ .

If $A \Phi$ is the transformation matrix of $\Phi$ with respect to an ordered basis
and $dim(Im(\Phi)) < dim(V )$ , **then the system of linear equations $A Φ x =
0$ has infinitely many solutions**

It's the infinitely many solutions part that I'm not quite seeing. Is that because if the kernal isn't trivial than that means that its infinite, because there could be an infinite number of linear combinations of elements in the null space that produce $0$?

Comment: The statement is in general false. One needs that the base field is infinite. In that case you can simply take some vector $0\neq v \in ker(\Phi)$ and then we have for all $\lambda \in F$ (your base field) that $$ A \Phi(\lambda v)  = A(\lambda \Phi(v))= \lambda A \Phi(v) = \lambda A 0 = \lambda 0 = 0. $$ As $\lambda v \neq \mu v$ for $\lambda \neq \mu$, we get infinitely many solutions $\lambda v$ for our equation.

Comment: Yes that makes perfect sense, thank you for replying.

Comment: You're welcome. I would suggest that you write up some answer yourself, filling the gaps in my sketch and maybe also explain what fails for finite base fields. This way the next person has a nice answer, this question is not on the unanswered list, you get some feedback on proof-writing and you even may earn some reputation. In any case, happy Holidays!